# Adding css for click event without reloading the page

Tags: jquery

Here is my script,i have added 5 images and submit button.when i click submit, if that image has visited class it will show tick mark otherwise i will show cross mark.Now my doubt is when i click again those images which has cross mark without reloading the page,i have to display tick mark instead of cross mark. Is it possible?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".img").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("visited");
    });
});

function validate() {
    $(".img").each(function() {
        $(this).after($(this).hasClass("visited") ? $(this).next().addClass("fa-check icon") : $(this).next().addClass("fa-times cross"));
        $(".fa").show();

    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You cannot find which are all `:visited`, as this is a security risk and many browsers are removing the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this for reference:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("img").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("visited");
    });
});

function validate() {
    $("img").each(function() {
      $(this).hasClass("visited") ? 
        $(this).next().text("v") :
        $(this).next().text("x");
    });
    return false;
}
```

```css
img{
  border:1px #00FF00 solid;
  margin:5px;
  width:100px;
}
.visited{
  border:1px #FF0000 solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"/>
<span></span>

<img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg"/>
<span></span>

<img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg"/>
<span></span>

<br/>

<img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg"/>
<span></span>

<img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.jpg"/>
<span></span>

<br/>

<button type="button" onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies or Local Storage. Using Local Storage, I have this for you:

```js
$(function () {
  localStorage["images"] = localStorage["images"] || "[]";
  var myImages = JSON.parse(localStorage["images"]);
  $(myImages.join(", ")).attr("src", "//placehold.it/150/ccf?text=Visited");
  $("img").click(function () {
    if (typeof localStorage != "undefined") {
      myImages.push("." + this.className);
      localStorage["images"] = JSON.stringify(myImages);
      $(this).attr("src", "//placehold.it/150/ccf?text=Visited");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
ul li {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Unvisited" class="img-1" /></li>
  <li><img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Unvisited" class="img-2" /></li>
  <li><img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Unvisited" class="img-3" /></li>
  <li><img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Unvisited" class="img-4" /></li>
  <li><img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Unvisited" class="img-5" /></li>
</ul>
```

Due to security reasons, Stack Snippet's output is sandboxed. Please check [**JSBin**](http://output.jsbin.com/hakejekaxi).